# ArcGIS Online - floating pop-ups in web map

Tags: arcgis-online, popup

Is there a way to make pop-ups in ArcGIS Online floating or draggable?

In case of long text in pop-up, moving with a whole map is for map users impractical.

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not possible in the map viewer. The 4.0 JS API has added the capability to dock your popups. Here is a link to a sample showing the popup docking. Just click the square box and it will dock it to the right corner.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/get-started-popupTemplate/live/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Just to piggyback on the above answer, here is a forum post on how to do it in JS 4.x. It includes example code.

[enter link description here](https://medium.com/@quarticsolutions/draggable-popups-with-angular-and-arcgis-api-for-javascript-4-x-5fd5e1673054)